# Plot frequency of elapsed times

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot frequency of the occurences of different elapsed times. The problem is, elapsed times are in range from **'00:00:10' to '31 days 04:42:17'**, and frequency is in range from 1 to 1561195. I tried with logarithmic scale but unsucessful.

```
trac_df['delta'].value_counts()

00:00:10    1561195
00:00:12      39395
00:00:08      23351
00:00:06        358
00:00:04        357
             ...   
00:37:21          1
00:56:14          1
01:52:53          1
01:03:30          1
12:11:20          1
Name: delta, Length: 2199, dtype: int64
```

I tried the following code, but x axis is not what i expect. I would like to have an x axis assigned with timedeltas as they are in dataframe. Any suggestions?

```
x = trac_df['delta'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hist(trac_df['delta'].astype('timedelta64[s]'))
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
trac_df['delta'].hist()

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 1 from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Comment: `trac_df['delta'].hist()`?

Comment: Returns: UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 1 from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Answer (score 0):

One option is to floor you series and plot the value counts:

```
df['delta'].dt.floor('15min').value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The problem is in the range of elapsed time; from 10sec to 31 days so none of the frequency (dt.floor()) is not working properly for this data...